# Validate deployment archive locally, i.e. without SF org

Tags: apex, deployment, validation

Is there any way to validate SF deployment archive locally, i.e. without triggering deployment to SF org?

The tool I'm looking for should be able to detect invalid references in Apex class, Aura components, Layouts, Translations etc. E.g. when Apex classes references non existent sobject field (assuming that all fields are present in deployment archive); or when translation is provided for non-existent label etc.

We've already had some basic set of validations written in Groovy to check for completeness of xml files etc. But it is just a tip of an iceberg. So I'm wondering whether there is an util like that (third-party or SF doesn't matter).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you use any type of IDE for development? I don't use VS (though I assume it has it) but Illuminated Cloud in IntelliJ builds a symbol table and alerts you to invalid references locally in your code.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves But there is no way just to extract that functionality into separate tool to execute it from command line etc. We need to integrate such validation into our CI process, i.e. checking that archive is complete and not broken.

Comment: I'm not aware of tools that exist (although I am interested in any answers you get), but you could look to do something yourself with SymbolTable/tooling api (presumably trying to copy how the IDEs do it) https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_symboltable.htm

Answer (score 0):

We use [Solenopsis](https://github.com/solenopsis/Solenopsis) for deployments at my job. You should be able to create a zip with all the components you want to validate and then leverage `deploy-zip [zip_file] --dryrun` to check for deployment errors.

Comment: It is actually doing a deployment to SF org just in validation mode, i.e. rolling back changes in the end. Doesn't fit into my requirements. We need to have local validation, i.e. without SF org and Internet connection at all)